# How to remove the external pause button?

Tags: javascript, html

On my website, I have this HTML code:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
        <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
             <audio src="http://204.2.199.166/7/288/80873/v1/rogers.akacast.akamaistream.net/tor925"
                volume="1.0">
            </audio>
        </span>
        <br>
        <br>
         <span class="trigger-audio fa fa-play">
            <audio src="https://cbc_r2_tor.akacast.akamaistream.net/7/364/451661/v1/rc.akacast.akamaistream.net/cbc_r2_tor"
                volume="1.0">
                 </audio>
            </span>

    </div>
    <br>
    <span class="fa fa-stop"></span>
```

And this Javascript:

```
function getAllSiblings(el){
            let parent = el.parentElement
            let children = Array.from(parent.children)
            let siblings = children.filter(child => {
                return child !== el
             })
            return siblings
        }
        let stop = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')
        let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
        stop.addEventListener('click',function(){
            buttons.forEach(button =>{
                let audio = button.firstElementChild
                if(!audio.paused){
                    audio.pause()
                    button.classList.add('fa-play')
                    button.classList.remove('fa-pause')

                }
            })
        })




        buttons.forEach(button =>{
            let audio = button.firstElementChild
            let siblings = getAllSiblings(button)
            button.addEventListener('click',function(){
                audio.play()
                button.classList.remove('fa-play')
                button.classList.add('fa-pause')
                siblings.forEach(sibling =>{
                    let siblingAudio = sibling.firstElementChild
                    sibling.addEventListener('click',function(){
                        siblingAudio.play()
                        audio.pause()
                        sibling.classList.remove('fa-play')
                        sibling.classList.add('fa-pause')
                        button.classList.remove('fa-pause')
                        button.classList.add('fa-play')

                    })
                })
            })
        })
```

Upon running, It forms an external "pause" button to pause the other audio players that are being played. Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3d22bj3a/7/). But I want to remove that pause button and pause the audio from the play button itself.

I tried to remove `let stop = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')` but that just stops the audio to be played at all. What would be the simplest way to fix this?

I'm a beginner so any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was hard to understand so I wrote the js from scratch. I think it's self-explanatory:

```
const audioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.trigger-audio')
const buttonToStopAllAudios = document.querySelector('.fa-stop')

const getAudioElementFromButton = buttonElement =>
  buttonElement.querySelector('audio')

const stopAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).pause()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-pause')
}

const playAudioFromButton = buttonElement => {
  // Pause the audio
  getAudioElementFromButton(buttonElement).play()

  // Update element classes
  buttonElement.classList.remove('fa-play')
  buttonElement.classList.add('fa-pause')
}

audioButtons.forEach(audioButton => {
  audioButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // I get this first because I have to pause all the audios before doing anything, so I have to know it this audio was paused or not
    const audioElement = getAudioElementFromButton(audioButton)
    const audioIsPaused = audioElement.paused

    // Stop all audios before starting this one
    audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)

    audioIsPaused
      ? playAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Play if it's paused
      : stopAudioFromButton(audioButton) // Pause if it's playing
  })
})

buttonToStopAllAudios.addEventListener('click', () => {
  audioButtons.forEach(stopAudioFromButton)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly :)